# What is the meaning of the letter L in the L1-norm and l2-norm metric?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

What does the letter 'L' in L1-norm, L2-norm, Lp-norm metric mean? Is it an abbreviation of a word or just a convention?

Previous literature has simply written about L1 or L2 paradigms without explaining what L means. For example:

1. Kwak N. Principal component analysis based on L1-norm maximization[J]. IEEE transactions on pattern analysis and machine intelligence, 2008, 30(9): 1672-1680.
2. Jajuga K. L1-norm based fuzzy clustering[J]. Fuzzy Sets and Systems, 1991, 39(1): 43-50.

Comment: It presumably stands for "Lebesgue", one of the primary figures of measure theory. Less as having a significant meaning, and more an acknowledgement of his role and a nod to him.

Comment: The Banach space now called $L_1$ was originally called simply $L$.  (And $L_\infty$ was called $M$.)  Perhaps you can find the space $L$ described in Banach's book.  Later, the spaces $L_p$ were named accordingly.  And subsequently the letters $L_p$ were extended to refer to norms formed in a similar way.

Answer (score 1):

The $L$ stands for [Lebesgue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space). This terminology originates in functional analysis where it is closely tied up with [Lebesgue integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration).